# Detailsgrid from list property on dataset in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datasource

I have a datagridView filled with my own object,
the representation of a table.

One of the attribute of my object is a list of childrens i'd like to display as a detailGrid.

So it's kind of like: 
-Main grid = header table
   -DetailGrids = Details Table

I've binded data this way so far:

```
dgvHeaders.datasource = lstMyHeaders
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `RowEnter` event to populate the Details Table.  The `DataBoundItem` property gets the list item that the row is bound to.

```
 Private Sub dgvHeaders_RowEnter(ByVal sender AsObject, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
        Handles dgvHeaders.RowEnter
    Dim myHeaderObject As myHeaderClass = dgvHeaders.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, myHeaderClass)
    dgvDetails.DataSource=myHeaderObject.lstMyDetails
  End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i'll get back to work Monday, I'l test it then...
looks like it'll do the job tho,
thanks!

Comment: Ow... thanks but i've just understand what I was doing wrong...

I tought there was an element like he Xceed's detailsGrid but there isn't any equivalent for dataGridView :S

My bad.